# Can send mail locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby, email, heroku, sinatra

I am having an issue sending mail via Heroku. I am able to send it locally, but for some reason every time I send it via Heroku I keep getting the 'Internal Server Error'. It had worked fine in the past, but all I had to do was to change my password, then the issue started. Does anyone know what's going on?

```
post '/' do
    require 'pony'
    name  = params[:name]
    mail = params[:mail]
    subject = params[:subject]
    body  = params[:body]

Pony.options = {
  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :location             => '/c/sendmail/./sendmail',
    :ssl                  => true,
    :arguments            => '-t',
    :port                 => '587',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name            => 'username',
    :password             => "password",
    :authentication       => :plain, # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
    :domain               => "localhost",
    # :tls                => true
  }
}


    Pony.mail(
        :to => 'stokes8671@gmail.com', 
        :from => name + '<' + mail + '>',
        :reply_to => mail,
        :subject => subject,
        :body => body)
```

Comment: Install New Relic or look into your log files and figure out what the error is.

Comment: How do I look into my log files?

Comment: Use `heroku logs --tail` command from the command line to view logs. This will show you any output that would normally happen on the terminal. Enable debugging mode in your web application and you'll get some useful messages.